# how to change the input of this program? (C Language)

Tags: objective-c, c

How can I replace the use of (FILE) and (fopen) with (scanf) to get the input values and send in these 2 functions?

I want to use this function in Objective-c code.
For more info you can see the whole code here [link](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/c.txt)

```
static void stemfile(FILE * f)
{  while(TRUE)
{  int ch = getc(f);
    if (ch == EOF) return;
    if (LETTER(ch))
    {  int i = 0;
        while(TRUE)
        {  if (i == i_max) increase_s();

            ch = tolower(ch); /* forces lower case */

            s[i] = ch; i++;
            ch = getc(f);
            if (!LETTER(ch)) { ungetc(ch,f); break; }
        }
        s[stem(s,0,i-1)+1] = 0;
        /* the previous line calls the stemmer and uses its result to
         zero-terminate the string in s */
        printf("%s",s);
    }
    else putchar(ch);
}
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{  int i;
    s = (char *) malloc(i_max+1);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {  FILE * f = fopen(argv[i],"r");
        if (f == 0) { fprintf(stderr,"File %s not found\n",argv[i]); exit(1); }
        stemfile(f);
    }
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain the constraints more carefully.  Where do you want to use `scanf()` (and why do you want to use it)?  However, you'll have to specify `stdin` explicitly to `ungetch()`.  Your version that takes a `FILE *` argument is more generally usable - which usually means 'better'.

Comment: thanks, in Main function i want to use scanf instead of fopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure why you would want to use `scanf()` in `main()`.  It would presumably mean changing the interface of `stemfile()` (including the name since it would no longer be processing a file) to take a character string as input.  And `scanf()` is going to make life difficult; it will read strings separated by blanks, which may be part of its attraction, but it will include any punctuation that is included in the 'word'.

As Randall noted, the code in the existing function is a little obsure; I think it could be written more simply as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define LETTER(x) isalpha(x)

extern int stem(char *s, int lo, int hi);

static void stemfile(FILE * f)
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        if (LETTER(ch))
        {
            char s[1024];
            int i = 0;
            s[i++] = ch; 
            while ((ch = getc(f)) != EOF && LETTER(ch))
                s[i++] = ch;
            if (ch != EOF)
                ungetc(ch, f);
            s[i] = '\0';
            s[stem(s, 0, i-1)+1] = 0;
            /* the previous line calls the stemmer and uses its result to
               zero-terminate the string in s */
            printf("%s", s);
        }
        else
            putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

I've slightly simplified things by making `s` into a simple local variable (it appears to have been a global, as does `imax`), removing `imax` and the `increase_s()` function.  Those are largely incidental to the operation of the function.

If you want this to process a (null-terminated) string instead, then:

```
static void stemstring(const char *src)
{
    char ch;
    while ((ch = *src++) != '\0')
    {
        if (LETTER(ch))
        {
            int i = 0;
            char s[1024];
            s[i++] = ch;
            while ((ch = *src++) != '\0' && LETTER(ch))
                s[i++] = ch;
            if (ch != '\0')
                src--;
            s[i-1] = '\0';
            s[stem(s,0,i-1)+1] = 0;
            /* the previous line calls the stemmer and uses its result to
               zero-terminate the string in s */
            printf("%s",s);
        }
        else
            putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

This systematically changes `getc(f)` into `*src++`, `EOF` into `\0`, and `ungetc()` into `src--`.  It also (safely) changes the type of `ch` from `int` (necessary for I/O) to `char`.  If you are worried about buffer overflow, you have to work a bit harder in the function, but few words in practice will be even 1024 bytes (and you could use 4096 as easily as 1024, with correspondingly smaller - infinitesimal - chance of real data overflowing the buffer.  You need to judge whether that is a 'real' risk for you.

The main program can become quite simply:

```
int main(void)
{
    char string[1024];
    while (scanf("%1023s", string) == 1)
        stemstring(string);
    return(0);
}
```

Clearly, because of the '1023' in the format, this will never overflow the inner buffer.  (NB: Removed the `.` from <s>`"%.1023s"`</s> in first version of this answer; `scanf()` is not the same as `printf()`!).

---

Challenged: does this work?

Yes - this code below (adding a dummy `stem()` function and slightly modifying the printing) works reasonably well for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define LETTER(x) isalpha(x)
#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))

static int stem(const char *s, int begin, int end)
{
    assert(s != 0);
    return MAX(end - begin - 3, 3);
}

static void stemstring(const char *src)
{
    char ch;
    while ((ch = *src++) != '\0')
    {
        if (LETTER(ch))
        {
            int i = 0;
            char s[1024];
            s[i++] = ch;
            while ((ch = *src++) != '\0' && LETTER(ch))
                s[i++] = ch;
            if (ch != '\0')
                src--;
            s[i-1] = '\0';
            s[stem(s,0,i-1)+1] = 0;
            /* the previous line calls the stemmer and uses its result to
               zero-terminate the string in s */
            printf("<<%s>>\n",s);
        }
        else
            putchar(ch);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[1024];
    while (scanf("%1023s", string) == 1)
        stemstring(string);
    return(0);
}
```

#### Example dialogue

```
H:  assda23
C:  <<assd>>
C:  23
H:  3423///asdrrrf12312
C:  3423///<<asdr>>
C:  12312
H:  12//as//12
C:  12//<<a>>
C:  //12
```

The lines marked `H:` are human input (the `H:` was not part of the input); the lines marked `C:` are computer output.

---

#### Next attempt

The trouble with concentrating on grotesquely overlong words (1023-characters and more) is that you can overlook the simple.  With `scanf()` reading data, you automatically get single 'words' with no spaces in them as input.  Here's a debugged version of `stemstring()` with debugging printing code in place.  The problem was two off-by-one errors.  One was in the assignment `s[i-1] = '\0';` where the `-1` was not needed.  The other was in the handling of the end of a string of letters; the `while ((ch = *src++) != '\0') left`src`one place too far, which led to interesting effects with short words entered after long words (when the difference in length was 2 or more).  There's a fairly detailed trace of the test case I devised, using words such as 'great' and 'book' which you diagnosed (correctly) as being mishandled.  The`stem()` function here simply prints its inputs and outputs, and returns the full length of the string (so there is no stemming occurring).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define LETTER(x) isalpha(x)
#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))

static int stem(const char *s, int begin, int end)
{
    int len = end - begin + 1;
    assert(s != 0);
    printf("ST (%d,%d) <<%*.*s>> RV %d\n", begin, end, len, len, s, len);
//    return MAX(end - begin - 3, 3);
    return len;
}

static void stemstring(const char *src)
{
    char ch;
    printf("-->> stemstring: <<%s>>\n", src);
    while ((ch = *src++) != '\0')
    {
        if (ch != '\0')
            printf("LP <<%c%s>>\n", ch, src);
        if (LETTER(ch))
        {
            int i = 0;
            char s[1024];
            s[i++] = ch;
            while ((ch = *src++) != '\0' && LETTER(ch))
                s[i++] = ch;
            src--;
            s[i] = '\0';
            printf("RD (%d) <<%s>>\n", i, s);
            s[stem(s, 0, i-1)+1] = '\0';
            /* the previous line calls the stemmer and uses its result to
               zero-terminate the string in s */
            printf("RS <<%s>>\n", s);
        }
        else
            printf("NL <<%c>>\n", ch);
    }
    //putchar('\n');
    printf("<<-- stemstring\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[1024];
    while (scanf("%1023s", string) == 1)
        stemstring(string);
    return(0);
}
```

The debug-laden output is shown (the first line is the typed input; the rest is the output from the program):

```
what a great book this is! What.hast.thou.done?
-->> stemstring: <<what>>
LP <<what>>
RD (4) <<what>>
ST (0,3) <<what>> RV 4
RS <<what>>
<<-- stemstring
-->> stemstring: <<a>>
LP <<a>>
RD (1) <<a>>
ST (0,0) <<a>> RV 1
RS <<a>>
<<-- stemstring
-->> stemstring: <<great>>
LP <<great>>
RD (5) <<great>>
ST (0,4) <<great>> RV 5
RS <<great>>
<<-- stemstring
-->> stemstring: <<book>>
LP <<book>>
RD (4) <<book>>
ST (0,3) <<book>> RV 4
RS <<book>>
<<-- stemstring
-->> stemstring: <<this>>
LP <<this>>
RD (4) <<this>>
ST (0,3) <<this>> RV 4
RS <<this>>
<<-- stemstring
-->> stemstring: <<is!>>
LP <<is!>>
RD (2) <<is>>
ST (0,1) <<is>> RV 2
RS <<is>>
LP <<!>>
NL <<!>>
<<-- stemstring
-->> stemstring: <<What.hast.thou.done?>>
LP <<What.hast.thou.done?>>
RD (4) <<What>>
ST (0,3) <<What>> RV 4
RS <<What>>
LP <<.hast.thou.done?>>
NL <<.>>
LP <<hast.thou.done?>>
RD (4) <<hast>>
ST (0,3) <<hast>> RV 4
RS <<hast>>
LP <<.thou.done?>>
NL <<.>>
LP <<thou.done?>>
RD (4) <<thou>>
ST (0,3) <<thou>> RV 4
RS <<thou>>
LP <<.done?>>
NL <<.>>
LP <<done?>>
RD (4) <<done>>
ST (0,3) <<done>> RV 4
RS <<done>>
LP <<?>>
NL <<?>>
<<-- stemstring
```

The techniques shown - printing diagnostic information at key points in the program - is one way of debugging a program such as this.  The alternative is stepping through the code with a source code debugger - `gdb` or its equivalent.  I probably more often use print statements, but I'm an old fogey who finds IDE's too hard to use (because they don't behave like the command line I'm used to).

Granted, it isn't your code any more, but I do think you should have been able to do most of the debugging yourself.  I'm grateful that you reported the trouble with my code.  However, you also need to learn how to diagnose problems in other people's code; how to instrument it; how to characterize and locate the problems.  You could then report the problem with precision - "you goofed with your end of word condition, and ...".

Comment: thank you so much for the time that you spent for this revision, actually the original code works in console, but i want to use it in an application in my Objective C program, i need to give a word  with ED or TION or ER suffix to this algorithm and receive the verb itself, that is why i want to change it in this way!

Comment: when i run the code it has ERROR! (Unknown conversion type character '.' in format) it runs but does not work, any word that i enter it just remove the last character from end!

Comment: I don't often use `scanf()` (too hard for me to get it to work the way I want it to work), and I forget the differences.  Remove the `.`; I put it there by false analogy with what `printf()` does; the emphasis is on _false_, sadly.

Comment: i tried without '.' still the program does not work properly! did you test it? was the result right ?

Comment: Yes - it works for me; see the marginally modified code with a dummy `stem()` function.  Note that the `scanf("%s")` only reads up to the first white space character, so your input lines containing blanks will be split into separate 'words' to be processed separately.

Comment: thanks, but it still does not work in some cases such as "great","book" it gives me "grea","boo" when i enter a word which does not have any suffix i expect to return the word itself, but if it has i expect to remove it and give me the root word. any way to fix this problem ?

Comment: I really Appreciate your effort to solve this problem. thank you indeed. I am Actually new in this field,that is why it's so hard to understand the concepts! .... i want to report another Problem again! this time it does not return the root word! you try "connection","connected" you will see that it return the same words!

Comment: I don't have a real `stem()` function; you do.  I can't demonstrate stemming properly because of that.  This is now over to you.  What does your `stem()` function do with the data that it is given?  That's where the magic is.  The 'Next Attempt' incarnation of the code simply echoes back the word that it is given.  For writing the 'real' `stem()` function, you are on your own.  I'm not even sure what's the best approach to take - apart from 'start small'.  That's where you need to become the local SME (subject matter expert), or contact someone else who is an SME (perhaps your supervisor).

Comment: dear Jonathan your very first code was right, if you just remove                    src--;  then it works perfectly, you helped me a lot, thanks indeed

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf()` function cannot be a direct replacement for the existing code. The existing code (which is not very well written IMO), splits up the input character stream into letters (defined by the `LETTER()` macro to be either uppercase or lowercase characters), and non-letters, and converts these letter sequences into lowercase before applying the `stem()` function to them.

The `scanf()` function, on the other hand extracts primitive types (int, char, double, etc.) and explicitly delimited strings from the input stream. The delimiters in the given code (i.e. anything that is not `LETTER()`) is too vague for `scanf()` (though not for a regular expression). `scanf()` needs a specific character on each end of a substring to look for. Also, `scanf()` cannot convert to lowercase automatically.

Assuming your input continues to be files, I think the easiest solution might be to leave the code as-is and use it, convoluted as it may be. There is nothing about it that shouldn't run as part of a larger Objective-C program. Objective-C, after all, still provides access to the C standard library, at least within the limits that the operating system sets (iOS is far more limiting than MacOS, if your are on an Apple platform).

The general problem here is that of tokenization: breaking an input sequence of unclassified symbols (like characters) into sequence of classified tokens (like words and spaces). A common approach to the problem is to use a [finite state machine/automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) (FSA/FSM) to apply parsing logic to the input sequence and extract the tokens as they are encountered. An FSA can be a bit hard to set up, but it is very robust and general.